# Ng-click in combination with angular material dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I have a `md-select` dropdown menu:

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedCategory">
    <md-option ng-repeat="category in dropdown" value="{{category.ID}}">
       {{category.prop}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

And i have a span like following. When i click on `span` with class `fa`, `selectedCategory` becomes 0 and the encapsulating span is closed (that is normal). BUT then, for some reason, `selectedCategory` takes again the previous value

```
<span ng-show="selectedCategory!=0">{{selectedCategory.prop}}
        <span class="fa fa-times delete-filter" ng-click="selectedCategory=0;"></span>   
</span>
```

Why does `selectedCategory` take previous value after 0? There is no other function influencing `selectedCategory`

ps: if i do the same in console (`selectedCategory=0`), it works.
ps2: if i do the same function in a function and call that from ng-click, it works clearly too.

Comment: Without more detail, hard to understand what you are trying to do.  But, are you sure you do not mean to use selectedCategory.id=0?  By using selectedCategory.prop, it appears that it is an object.  Also review https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect, especially the second example.

Comment: I got your point but selectedCategory is just an id of category that should be chosen. I use that in all places. As i said, if i do the same operations in places other than inside ng-click, its working.